# What did the Pandavas have to do before reaching heaven?

Tags: mahabharata, pandavas, yudhisthira, kauravas, swarga

Popular TV shows describe Yudhishthira's journey to heaven after each of the other Pandavas fell (or fail). He was accompanied by Yama Raj in the disguise of a dog.

He had to undergo a series of tests before being able to meet his brothers, wife and cousins.

My questions:

- Did the other Pandavas and Kauravas have to undergo any test or punishment before reaching heaven?
- What is the difference between what Yudhishthira had to do and what other Pandavas and the Kauravas had to do to reach heaven?

Comment: Karna hs not righteous

Comment: I think the answer is Yudhishthira was the only one who reached heaven alive.

Comment: If he is righteous why he had vision of all his brothers in hell whereas kauravas in heaven so seeing that yuddishtra preferred hell instead heavyenin mahabharata tatparya nirnaya of sriman madhvacharya said that yuddistra disbelieve lord krishna on 2 occasions during dronacharya death he was asked Krishna to tell lie of ashwatthamma death but instead he lies in wishper by telling ahswattama elepgant in a hushed tone

Comment: Okay, tell me the difference between Yudhishthira's and others' journey to the heaven. Yudhishthira did only one wrong as per [this video (36:20)](https://youtube.com/watch?v=U3PmInh93Y0&t=36m20s). So, I am assuming he was the only one to reach heaven alive.

Comment: Going to heaven with body is not a virtue even Arjuna had done that.

Comment: @PrasannaR Thanks for your comments. See, **I don't know about :** i. Whether or not Yudhishthira was virtuous ii. Whether or not going to heaven with body is virtuous. **Also, I am unable to deduce** what you want me to do now with the question. **So, I think you should:** i. Suggest an edit to remove the *debatable* or *ambiguous* details from this question (if any question is still there) or ii. Let me know if my assumption is correct (if so, I will delete this question) or iii. VTC this question (if it can't be answered because either everything is wrong here or this is opinion based).

Comment: How did pandavas redeem their sin before going to heaven? That would be the correct question

Comment: They got their flaws told by yuddistra before their death

Comment: @PrasannaR *They got their flaws told by yuddistra before their death.* Is that the answer?

Comment: Yes to redeem one sin one can do prayachita by homa  and or  also flaws they have committed should be told to them at their time of death so they can repent and can vow not to do that again because are already near to death this was ancient practice but become obsolete but surprising Christian follow thus religiously but not at the time death became there is high chance they can commit similar offence again even if they repent

Comment: @PrasannaR I am editing the question as you suggested. Kindly add an answer after I edit this question.

Comment: @PrasannaR - *"If he is righteous why he had vision of all his brothers in hell"* if you listen to upanyasams the answer is given there itself. All kings have to have a vision of naraka before they can go to swarga because, as a king, they have to know what tortures their subjects undergo due to sin. It is to keep themselves in check in svarga. Indra/Yama themselves mention this to Yudhishtir

Comment: from your point from upanyasa quote this seems to interpolation where every king had vision of naraka because many king attained moksha without have the vision.. also many kings attained swarga without this vision. Keep themselves in check in svarga.. do person in svarga have ability todo wrong thing? what is the consequence of karma there in swarga.. so you had opened a Pandora's box.. of svarga karma.. see upanyasakara might say anything but we need to get to the context.. what im quoting is from MBTN of Sriman Madhvacharya @mar

Comment: @PrasannaR - i'm talking about svarga, not moksha. who said kings attained svarga without vision of naraka ? in upanaysam, vidwans said that from svarg, you have vision of naraka, so you won't really be able to enjoy too much since you can see suffering. *"Keep themselves in check in svarga"* - doesn't mean avoiding paap, it means avoiding indulgence too much.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is to renounce the kingdom and appoint Parikshit, the son of Abhimanyu as the king and Kripa as preceptor which they did.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m17/m17001.htm

> Yudhishthira made over the kingdom to the son of his uncle by his Vaisya wife. Installing Parikshit also on their throne, as king, the eldest brother of the Pandavas, filled with sorrow, addressed Subhadra, saying, ‘This son of thy son will be the king of the Kurus. The survivor of the Yadus, Vajra, has been made a king. Parikshit will rule in Hastinapura, while the Yadava prince, Vajra, will rule in Shakraprastha. He should be protected by thee. Never set thy heart on unrighteousness.’

Arjuna had to give his Gandiva away as told by Agni Deva, the deity of fire

> ‘Ye heroic sons of Pandu, know me for the deity of fire. O mighty-armed Yudhishthira, O Bhimasena that art a scorcher of foes, O Arjuna, and ye twins of great courage, listen to what I say! Ye foremost ones of Kuru’s race, I am the god of fire. The forest of Khandava was burnt by me, through the puissance of Arjuna and of Narayana himself. Let your brother Phalguna proceed to the woods after casting off Gandiva, that high weapon. He has no longer any need of it. That precious discus, which was with the high-souled Krishna, has disappeared (from the world). When the time again comes, it will come back into his hands. This foremost of bows, Gandiva, was procured by me from Varuna for the use of Partha. Let it be made over to Varuna himself.’
>
> "At this, all the brothers urged Dhananjaya to do what the deity said. He then threw into the waters (of the sea) both the bow and the couple of inexhaustible quivers.